# How can one sort a list of complex numbers in increasing order with respect to their imaginary part in Maple?

Tags: maple

I am a beginner at Maple and am attempting to use the sort function to order a list of complex numbers according to their imaginary part, however I can find no function options that help. Will I have to use a loop?

Comment: according to http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=sort
all you need is specifying the sorting function being something like Img(), sorry I dont know maple either

Answer (score 4):

Maple's `sort` command allows you to use a custom procedure as the predicate to compare two elements.

For example, to sort a list of numeric entries according by their imaginary component:

```
L:=[ 3+4*I, 6-I, -3, 2, 0.4*I ];

                  L := [3 + 4 I, 6 - I, -3, 2, 0.4 I]

sort( L, (a,b) -> Im(a)<Im(b) );

                    [6 - I, 2, -3, 0.4 I, 3 + 4 I]
```

You could also use a comparison procedure which compared the real components, in the case that the imaginary components were equal.

```
p := proc(a,b)
  if Im(a) < Im(b) then
    true;
  elif Im(a) = Im(b) then
    if Re(a) < Re(b) then
      true;
    else
      false;
    end if;
  else
    false;
  end if;
end proc:

L:=[ 3+4*I, 6-I, -3, 2, 0.4*I, -3+4*I, -6-I ];

sort( L, p );

           [-6 - I, 6 - I, -3, 2, 0.4 I, -3 + 4 I, 3 + 4 I]
```

The comparison procedures above utilizes `<` under `evalb` for its boolean evaluation. That combination handles elements of type `numeric`, but does not handle elements which are of type `realcons` but not of type `numeric`.

For example, the following does not return `true` or `false`, since `sqrt(2)` is not of type `numeric`. It simply returns unevaluated.

```
evalb( sqrt(2) < 5 );

                                1/2
                               2    < 5
```

By utilizing the `is` command we can strengthen the test to also handle such quantities of type `realcons`. Eg,

```
is( sqrt(2) < 5 );

                                 true
```

This reasoning carries over to `sort` as well,

```
L := [ 3+4*I, 6-I, sqrt(2)*I, -3, 2, 0.4*I ];

                                     1/2
              L := [3 + 4 I, 6 - I, 2    I, -3, 2, 0.4 I]

sort( L, (a,b) -> Im(a)<Im(b) );               
 Error, sort: comparison function argument, (a, b) -> Im(a) < Im(b),
 must be a function that always returns true or false

sort( L, (a,b) -> is(Im(a)<Im(b)) );

                                       1/2
                [6 - I, 2, -3, 0.4 I, 2    I, 3 + 4 I]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - that's really helpful!